# How to make my Form scrollable on keyboard input

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, scrollview

I have designed a form in Flutter. I want to make it **scrollable** whenever keyboard opens up so that user can fill the fields that gets hidden below the keyboard. Here is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

[image]

I have tried this using `SingleChildScrollView()`, however, its not working. I have tried wrapping various widgets inside the `SingleChildScrollView()` but its not working. I have also tried to wrap this inside `Expanded()` widget but still unable to achieve my goal.

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text("Name"),
                  subtitle: TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      hintText: 'Type your name here',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        
            ElevatedButton(
              style: style,
              child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
               'Update',
               style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
            ),
          ),
             onPressed: () {
            }
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

Comment: after wrapping with `SingleChildScrollView` can you try `futter clean` and rebuild the app?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have tried flutter clean, still its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Wrapping it with Padding

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
```

Comment: Well it's working after wrapping with padding and then with SingleChildScrollView() but the Update button below the form goes on missing until the keyboard is open.

Comment: Move the padding to the Top Container instead of Form

Answer (score 0):

The SingleChildScrollView widget should solve your issue. It may be where you are placing it. It needs to wrap the whole form not just an individual list tile. Below is an example using you example as a base.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        ListTile(
          title: const Text("1"),
          subtitle: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              hintText: 'Type your name here',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text("2"),
          subtitle: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              hintText: 'Type your name here',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text("3"),
          subtitle: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              hintText: 'Type your name here',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text("4"),
          subtitle: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              hintText: 'Type your name here',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text("5"),
          subtitle: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              hintText: 'Type your name here',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: I have done that also. But still it's not working for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue sometime back and I managed to mitigate it by wrapping the column containing the widgets with a `SingleChildScrollView` and giving it `Axis.vertical`. Then go to the parent scaffold and set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `true`.

`Depends on how your widget tree looks`

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    ///
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     child: Column(  /// Your widget
        children: []
      ),
     ),
    );
```